# Issue Setting Up Django Database Access API Using SQLite

Tags: python, django

I just started using Django, and I am going through the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/) to build my first app, but I am running into some kind of issue related to the database access API for SQLite.

My directory structure looks like this:

[image]

The only files I have edited are `models.py` and `settings.py` and it is all code from the documentation.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    # ...
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    # ...
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.choice_text

import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Question(models.Model):
    # ...
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

The only changes I have made to `settings.py` are adding my timezone `TIME_ZONE = 'US/Pacific'` and adding `'polls',` to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

(For full disclosure, I have set up my `urls.py` just to test hello world, which is not part of the documentation, but I don't think that's causing the issue.  Here's the code for that if it's relevant.)

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.debug import default_urlconf
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world!!!')

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', hello),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    #url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    #url(r'^$', default_urlconf),
)
```

Now, the issue I'm running into is when I get to the "Playing with the API" section.  When I open a `python manage.py shell` for the second time in that section, I'm supposed to be able to use the command `Question.objects.all()` and get the result `[<Question: What's up?>]` with "What's up?" being the value of `question_text`.  The problem is I'm still getting the result `[<Question: Question object>]` instead of the `question_text` value.

I've gone back and re-created my app three times in the hope that I missed something during the setup, but I get the same issue every time and I seem to be following the documentation exactly.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: have you added the `__repr__` or the `__unicode__` method to the Question class?

Comment: You mean using `__unicode__` instead of `__str__` ?

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but when I use the command Question.objects.filter(question_text__startswith='What')`` I get `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'question_text' into field. Choices are: id`

Comment: This seems unrelated with the naming issue. But about the `FieldError`, try running, `python manage.py makemigrations polls` and `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: What happens when you do `str(Question.objects.first())` on the shell?

Comment: I've done the migrations before, but I tried them again, and it didn't help.  Running `str(Question.objects.first())` on the shell returns `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Question' is not defined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88634/discussion-between-darkryder-and-teldridge11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that the contents of `models.py` match with what's given in the tutorial

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):              # __str__ on Python 3
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):              # __str__ on Python 3
        return self.choice_text
```

Also make sure that the migrations are up to date.

If you're running python 2, use `__unicode__` else use `__str__`.

That should solve the problem for you.